# manipulate list by adding string to each item in python

Tags: python

I have to lists as below:

```py
list1 = [[33, 35, 50, 52, 67, 69, 82, 84, 86, 99],
         [01, 16, 18, 35, 50, 52, 67, 69, 84, 08]]
```

I would like to have this as the output:

```
['select * from table where id in (33, 35, 50, 52, 67, 69, 82, 84, 86, 99)', 'select * from table where id in (01, 16, 18, 35, 50, 52, 67, 69, 84, 08)']
```

would appreciate your help :)

Comment: I didn't get what you need. Please provide an input and an output an try ton explain what that SQL command should mean

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[33, 35, 50, 52, 67, 69, 82, 84, 86, 99], [1, 16, 18, 35, 50, 52, 67, 69, 84, 8]]

new_list = []

for sub_list in list1:
    new_list.append(f"select * from table where id in {tuple(sub_list)}")

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```py
['select * from table where id in (33, 35, 50, 52, 67, 69, 82, 84, 86, 99)', 'select * from table where id in (1, 16, 18, 35, 50, 52, 67, 69, 84, 8)']
```

Careful with `01` and `08` instead of `1` and `8`, this would raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good task for list comprehension:

```
command = "select * from table where id in"
new_list = [f"{command} ({', '.join([str(i) for i in sub_list])})" for sub_list in list1]
```

This code shows how to form the target string. It can be useful if the parenthesis are of some other type.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a tuple to get that parentheses layout, and then a string to add it to the select statement.

```
list1 = [[33, 35, 50, 52, 67, 69, 82, 84, 86, 99],
         [1, 16, 18, 35, 50, 52, 67, 69, 84, 8]]

newList = []
for i in list1:
    newList.append("select * from table where id in " + str(tuple(i)))
print(newList)
```

You will need to remove the leading 0's before the 1 and 8 though, otherwise you will get an error.